# Spring + Spring MVC dependency injection without using @Autowire

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm building an application using Spring and Spring MVC. For me using @Autowired is not an option (is a requirement).

I have build a web.xml file like:

```
<!-- Spring context -->
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>namespace</param-name>
        <param-value>mvc-dispatcher-context</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I load Spring context and Spring MVC Servlet.

My mvc-dispatcher-context.xml file looks like:

```
<beans ...>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pacage.controller"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So I can use @Controller annotation in my controllers...

And on my applicationContext.xml I have my Spring beans defined, such as my Services in this case "OneService.java"

I have One controller as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

    private OneService oneService;
    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Where I want to inject OneService which is defined in applicationContext.xml file.
I've tried several ways but I can't get it working, always getting an NullPointerException when using my service inside the controller.

Is there any way to use beans defined in applicationContext.xml inside this mvc servlet?

[UPDATE]

If I define all my applicatonContext inside my servlet I can't get it working. Is there any way to make servlet context a child of application context just to be able to use application context beans?

Comment: "Is a requirement"? If you're using `@Controller`, you're already using Spring-specific annotations, but of course `@Inject` is always an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Could I do this without using annotations?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but you could also write the application in C. Annotations are the best practice in Web development, and for good reasons.

Comment: I know it's the best practice but it does not deppend on me to use annotations...

Comment: You need to define getter/setter in your controller for your service. Setter should get used for wiring if bean is properly defined. Also I don't understand why `@Autowire` shouldn't be used? Go for `@Resource` then...

Comment: To be honest I don't understand too but is a requirement to configure DI via XML not via annotations. I have my services defined in applicationContext.xml and my controller inside servlet but I can't inject there my services. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Application context is already the "father" so beans defined in there are available to beans defined in its children. But you can defined both in the application context if you want. 
The problem may be how you are trying to inject the service.

If you add @Autowired to you service it will work because that bean is available in your controller, but if you don't want to use annotations then you need to explicitly create and inject the beans in your xml contexts. 
First you need to add a setter in your controller:

```
public void setOneService(OneService oneService) {
    this.oneService = oneService;
}
```

Then in your application context you would do:

```
<bean id="mainController" class="com.package.controller.MainController">
    <property name="oneService" ref="oneService" />
</bean>
<bean id="oneService" class="com.package.service.OneService">
</bean>
```

You can still do this and keep the service declaration in the application context and the controller in the servlet context.